# How to pass environment variable to mongo script

Tags: mongodb, shell

I want to pass the environment variable named `file_path` to js file.

I am using the following syntax:

```
mongo --eval "var file_path='$file_path'" < aggregation.js
```

**Output:**

```
MongoDB shell version: 3.2.9-rc0
connecting to: test
```

**Note:**

It does not execute `aggregation.js` file.
only it pass the argument.

Comment: For anyone else surprised that mongo doesn't support this - there's a request for it here: https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-4895

Answer (score 21):

This worked for me:

```
mongo --eval "var my_var = '$MY_VAR'" my_script.js
```

Leave out the `<`.  `mongo` will process any remaining arguments on the command line as files to be executed/interpreted, but apparently combining the shell input redirect with `--eval` causes the javascript namespace to be reset.

I assume but cannot confirm that this is because filenames passed as arguments are processed via the `load()` mechanism, which according to https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/method/load/, behaves as follows:

> After executing a file with load(), you may reference any functions or variables defined the file from the mongo shell environment.

Answer (score 11):

According to [this commit](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo/commit/0f69c4c2efa53995188601f893b487e01f3f244f#diff-35d230504300da86114986934ef35d97), it looks like there's a native method called `_getEnv()` that can do it for you.

```js
const username = _getEnv('DB_USERNAME')
const password = _getEnv('DB_PASSWORD')
// use the username and password
```

Comment: Since MongoDB 5.0 `mongo` shell is deprecated and replaced by `mongosh`
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongo/#mongodb-binary-bin.mongo
Which does not support _getEnv as far as I can tell. Any suggestions?

Comment: @ReFruity, `mongosh` is also a Node.js shell, so simply use [process.env](https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#processenv): `process.env["DB_USERNAME"]`

Answer (score 7):

Since Mongo `4.0.5` it is possible to utilize some of the new admin functions to load text files and execute programs.
So you can write a Javascript function to execute a shell script that provides the value of an environment variable:

```
function getEnvValue(envVar, defVal) {
   var ret= run("sh", "-c", `printenv ${envVar} >/tmp/${envVar}.txt`);
   if (ret != 0) return defVal;
   return cat(`/tmp/${envVar}.txt`)
}
```

And then using it like this:

```
db.createCollection("myCol",
 { capped: true,
   size: getEnvValue('MYCOL_MAX_SIZE_GB', 2)*1024*1024*1024
});
```

This relies on the host shell but was acceptable in my case (Docker).

Was also trying to read the `environ` directly:

```
cat('/proc/self/environ').split('\0') # Doesn't work
```

but it only gets the first variable. I guess because of the null characters...

Comment: I have used your approach but I had to had the --null parameter to printenv to avoid new line.    `printenv --null ${envVar} >/tmp/${envVar}.txt`

Comment: The `run()` seems to be undocumented, see [Native Methods](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/js-native/) Do you think it is save to use it?

Answer (score 6):

Looks like Native Method `shellGetEnv()` has been added meanwhile, see [MongoDB GitHub](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo/commit/0f69c4c2efa53995188601f893b487e01f3f244f#diff-35d230504300da86114986934ef35d97)

Function is available (thanks to @orgads):

```
_getEnv("PATH")
```

However, it is not documented and there is [no statement yet](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-4895?filter=10912) whether it may be used by end-user or only as internal command.

The new MongoDB Shell, `mongosh`, is a fully functional JavaScript and [Node.js 14.x](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest-v14.x/api/) REPL environment,  thus you can access environment variables with `process.env`, e.g.

```
process.env["PATH"]
```

Comment: The function name is `_getEnv`. `shellGetEnv` is the native implementation.

Comment: `process.env` worked a treat in `mongosh`

Answer (score 0):

There's a suggestion from the mongo [change request](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-4895):

```
alias mongo="export | sed 's/declare -x /env./' > shell.js; mongo $@; rm shell.js;"
```

Then in `~/mongorc.js`:

```
var env = {};
load('shell.js');
```

Comment: Old `mongo` shell is not supported anymore. Thus, this proposal would be outdated.

Answer (score 0):

In case of Mongo 6 use `process.env`:

```
$ export A='a"a'
$ mongosh --quiet --eval 'console.log(process.env.A)'
a"a
```

Before 6.x:

```
$ q_A=`jq --arg v "$A" -n '$v'`
$ mongosh --quiet --eval "console.log($q_A)"
a"a
```

By the way, the `mongo` image (`docker`) [comes with `jq`](https://github.com/docker-library/mongo/blob/840d7ed246dc72ae9e84ce92b9f5a6f9dfa4d6e1/6.0/Dockerfile#L22), although that might change.