# Access shell environment in mongo shell

Tags: mongodb

Is there a way to access shell env variable in the mongo shell?
In nodejs, it can access an environment variable in script like following.

```
var uri = process.env['MONGOLAB_URI']
```

I am looking for the same way in mongo script.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to pass environment variable to mongo script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39444467/how-to-pass-environment-variable-to-mongo-script)

Answer (score 2):

You can use a redirection like this :

```
NAME="John"

mongo << EOF
use testDB
db.person.findOne({"name":"$NAME"})
EOF
```