# How to get environment variable in mongo shell?

Tags: mongodb

I am trying to load a file from folder;

I have a system environment variable as follows

HOME="/home/stack/FolderName"

How can I get this path in js file

```
$mongo databasename  script.js
```

in script file

```
 var data = cat(env.getPath("HOME") +"/requiredData.csv")
 var arr = data.split(",");
 arr.forEach((a) =>  db.collection.insert(a))
```

data in requireddata.csv is as follows
     a,b,c,d

thanks in advance.

Comment: Please see this post - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39444467/how-to-pass-environment-variable-to-mongo-script

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to access mongodb environment variables via mongo shell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70603199/how-to-access-mongodb-environment-variables-via-mongo-shell)