# how to access mongodb environment variables via mongo shell

Tags: database, mongodb

I've try to get env variables via mongo-initi.js and mongo docker-compose.yml ,
If it is possible to get mongodb docker containers env variable via mongo shell?

Answer (score 2):

Which shell do you use? The legacy `mongo` shell (I prefer term "classic shell") or the new `mongosh`?

In the new `mongosh`, it is easy. The `mongosh` is a Node.js shell, simply use [process.env](https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#processenv)

In legacy shell `mongo` you can use undocumented function `_getEnv()` or you pass environment variable in `--eval`, for example

```
mongo --eval "var my_var = '$MY_VAR';" ...
```

See [How to pass environment variable to mongo script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39444467/how-to-pass-environment-variable-to-mongo-script/67037065#67037065)